# Sending an i calendar as mail body in php mailer

Tags: php, laravel, email, phpmailer, icalendar

I am using php mailer to send mails to recipients and I need to send i calendar events, i know how to send them as an attachment but i want to send them in mail body. is it possible?

```
$message = "You have been invited to the online meeting '".$schedule->schedule_name.
                                    "', On ".$date." (".$start_time."-".$end_time.") by Tuti.World \n
                                    (See attachments for more details)";

        $ical_content = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
                                        VERSION:2.0
                                        PRODID://Drupal iCal API//EN
                                        BEGIN:VEVENT
                                        UID:http://www.icalmaker.com/event/d8fefcc9-a576-4432-8b20-40e90889affd
                                        DTSTAMP:".$date.
                                        "DTSTART:".$start_time.
                                        "DTEND:".$end_time.
                                        "SUMMARY:Online Meeting
                                        END:VEVENT
                                        END:VCALENDAR";



$mail->msgHTML($message);
$mail->addStringAttachment($ical_content,$file,'base64','text/calendar');
$mail->send();
```

these are the code blocks of the current mail body and calendar event...

Comment: Do you mean you want to put the iCal file inline with the contents? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: yes i was trying to add the i cal to the body, i cal doesn't need to be a file if its possible. i haven't worked with php mailer or i cal events before so i don't know the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer has built-in iCal support, which it uses to create a third `text/calendar` part within a `multipart/alternative` structure. This is "the RFC way", but unfortunately iCal clients are a total mess, and nothing works consistently across Outlook, Gmail, and Apple Mail. The best approach is to go with the standard structure, but also add the same data as an attachment (like you're already doing). The only change you need to make in your code is to add this line:

```
$mail->Ical = $ical_content;
```

You also need to be very careful with your iCal content - Outlook is particularly picky, and the tiniest thing wrong will result in it not working at all, so I recommend testing using an iCal string *generated by* Outlook to start with, so that you isolate your iCal sending from any other issues you have relating to what's in it.

Comment: Glad to hear that! If this has answered your question, please mark this answer as such (click the checkmark next to it).

Comment: It does not insert an i cal event in the body, it creates another attachment so it does not still provide an answer to my question. but the pointers about how i cal working was helpful

Comment: Which approach works is highly dependent on what client you're using. Some use the multipart, some want an attachment. There is no way to have it work equally well in all clients while only having a single copy, so you have to compromise. If you want to have it work in all clients with only one copy of the iCal data, you're currently asking for the impossible. Fro example, google calendar invitations do nothing special in Apple Mail or Outlook, they just have a ics attachment. Similarly, Outlook multiparts do not work in Gmail or Apple Mail. An ics attachment is always a viable fallback.

Comment: can i get an answer how to publish one on gmail and apple mail?

Comment: Look at the address and send a different format to each one. That's not a great strategy because you can't tell what client a recipient is using by looking at their address – it's entirely possible to be reading gmail.com messages in Outlook, and outlook.com messages in Gmail. I have both office365 and gmail accounts, but I read both from Apple Mail.

Comment: Yes that would be a hard problem to tackle i see

Answer (score 0):

I have been using phpmailer for years for events and it has always worked. I always have problems only with apple. With IOS 13 I had to wait 4 months for them to fix it. Now with 14.4 the same problem, the yes/no/maybe buttons don't come out anymore so if I insert the event from iphone it doesn't synchronize it with outlook. Vice versa it works. If I accept it from iphone, I update the event and when I accept it from outlook automatically finds on the iphone what was an isolated event and updates it, I assume because the id is unique anyway. It's frunstrante apple side that continues to make mistakes.